# ajaxSetup() equivalent for Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) for the first time. Does it have something akin to  jQuery's [ajaxSetup()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) method, in order to set authorization headers for future requests? I can't find any evidence that it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create authorisation headers using Request, saving to a variable allows it to be reusable. Note that according to the jQuery docs, setting default values using jQuery.ajaxSetup() is [not recommended](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

```
let href = '/linkToPage';
let request = new Request(href, {
   method: 'GET',
   mode: 'same-origin',
   redirect: 'follow',
   headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
   })
});
```

Then use the fetch request as usual

```
fetch(request).then((response) => {
   if(response.ok) {
      return response.text();
   }
   throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then((text) => {
   if(text.trim() != ''){
      console.log(text);
   }
}).catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```